# show coordinate of nmds plot in R

Tags: r, mds

I was newly user of R,
I want use this for make me reduce many dimension (60 column and 60 row) matrix I have,
So I got the plot with this command

```
library(vegan)
set.seed(2)
example_NMDS=metaMDS(Dim_Matrix,k=4,trymax=100)
plot(example_NMDS)
```

But, what I want to get was the coordinat of the point in ploting result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reffering on http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/metaMDS.html

We can get the coordinat/value/points by using this command

```
scores(example_NMDS)
```